# How do you spin up a new spine app using the spine.app cli?

Tags: spine.js

I'm attempting to use the spine.app cli and I'm encountering a couple of errors and I'm uncertain what the root cause actually is.

The guide found at: http://spinejs.com/docs/started gives these steps

```
spine app my-app
cd my-app
npm install .
hem server
```

following these steps, initially yields this error on the terminal:

```
Cannot find module: es5-shimify. Have you run `npm install .` ?
```

Investigating, it seems es5-shimify has been deprecated in favor of es5-shim, so my initial inclination was to replace the dependency to es5-shim. So I updated setup.coffee to `require('es5-shim')`, and I updated the referenced slug.json module and restarted the server. This seems to get me a little further, but still produces an error ( though not in the terminal, instead in the chrome console )

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

This appears to be occurring on line 8 of public/index.html. I did some debugging here and it appears that require('jqueryify') is returning undefined, and I'm not certain what the expected result is. Any guidance on the right way to approach this process or perhaps information on what the root issue might be would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest version try again.

The package.json as following

`{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "spine": "~1.3.0"
  }
}`

all others dependencies has been removed,and it works for me.

Comment: Aw yes, I forgot to answer my own question, I got some help from the guys at spinejs and they helped fix up the toolset XD